# How to get result as json from schedule task

Tags: c#, json, powershell, json.net

I'm working on a PowerShell script which is calling C# method to enable/ disable a specific task.

Everything is working fine But I only want to get the Json result. Instead I'm getting the below result, like TaskName , TaskPath and other unwanted white space .  I'm using `return $properties | ConvertTo-Json` in my PowerShell script to convert it but looks like when we do Enable-ScheduledTask PowerShell automatically added TaskPath and TaskName.

Can anyone suggestion how I can avoid TaskName/TaskPath and get only Json data in {}.

[image]

Comment: You mean `$properties.TaskPath | ConvertTo-Json` ?

Comment: @Theo I'm already using this $properties.TaskPath | ConvertTo-Json. Usually when we run command for enable , disable ,start ,stop PowerShell return result as TaskPath, TaskName as I mentioned in my image. I don't want that info I am only looking for Json  data {  "message" : " successfully executed action " }

Comment: Your question says _I'm using `return $properties | ConvertTo-Json`_, which clearly is different than`$properties.TaskPath | ConvertTo-Json.`... Anyway, since we don't know what your C# method actually returns, its all a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution. I had to use out-null to suppress the output that's it.
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $TaskPath -TaskName $taskName | Out-Null

I followed this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-7.1